# How can I divide two user inputs using only loops and using any operations is not allowed?

Tags: c#, for-loop, console-application, division, accumulator

```
Console.Write("Input Value for A: ");

int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Input Value for B: ");
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int acc = 0;
for (int i = a; a >= b; a--)
{
    acc += b;
}

Console.Write("The quotient is {0}", acc);
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Are you limited to only subtract operation and have to get result of `A / B` or what? [This algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/186421)?

Comment: No sir, I am not allowed to use any operation even subtraction. @Sinatr

Comment: Please help me this is really hard for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a trick question, and therefore I immediately dislke it. The solution is the following:

```
var quotient = 0;   
for (var acc = b; acc <= a; acc += b, quotient += 1);
Console.Write($"The quotient of {a} divided by {b} is {quotient}");
```

The trick being that you are still using operations, but as a step in the loop itself and not as an explicit operation inside the loop body, which is probably the point of the excericse.

*UPDATE*: This code only gives accurate results if `a` and `b` have the same sign.

Comment: Btw @InBetween what code do I have to use in order to get its remainder?

Comment: @KimberlyIradiel `int remainder; for (remainder = a; remainder >= b; remainder -= b, quotient += 1);`

Comment: Thank you so much! @InBetween